# React native geolocation service updating too quickly?

Tags: react-native, geolocation

The update rate is too fast specifically when driving. I tried to set it to only update every 5 seconds or every 10 meters whichever is slower to update

What i currently have:

```
     Geolocation.watchposition(
         {distanceFilter:10, interval:60000, fastestInterval:5000,
         enableHighAccuracy:true,}
      )
```